# Can't locate Text/Soundex.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I was installing repeatsmasker and it apparently seems to work because it shows "Congratulations! RepeatMasker is now ready to use."
 But when I run it it reports "Can't locate Text/Soundex.pm...". so I installed the module by "sudo cpan Text::Soundex", and by the end it tells me "Text::Soundex is up to date (3.05)." It seems the module is already installed, but RepeatMasker still has the same problem, as I'll show you in this code:

```
fragua@picci:~/RM/RepeatMasker$ sudo cpan Text::Soundex
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Reading '/home/fragua/.cpan/Metadata'
 Database was generated on Fri, 19 Apr 2019 22:17:03 GMT
Text::Soundex is up to date (3.05).

fragua@picci:~/RM/RepeatMasker$ ./RepeatMasker -s -lib /home/fragua/RepeatScout-1.0.5/ObiINK5k_repeats_filtered1.fasta /home/fragua/Documenti/Workdirectory/ObiINC5k.fa
Can't locate Text/Soundex.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Text::Soundex module) (@INC contains: /home/fragua/RM/RepeatMasker /home/fragua/perl5/lib/perl5 /home/fragua/anaconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/fragua/anaconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /home/fragua/anaconda/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/fragua/anaconda/lib/5.26.2 .) at /home/fragua/RM/RepeatMasker/Taxonomy.pm line 80.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/fragua/RM/RepeatMasker/Taxonomy.pm line 80.
Compilation failed in require at ./RepeatMasker line 310.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./RepeatMasker line 310.
```

I installed RepeatMasker in another computer without problems, but I don't know why now I encontered this problem

Comment: It looks like you're using a Perl version installed in your home directory, and I bet `sudo cpan` is using the OS Perl installation. So the module is installed for that copy, but not for the copy your program is using.

Comment: Ok... can you suggest me a way to fix it?

Comment: If that is indeed the issue, the module needs to be installed via your local copy of perl.

Comment: Sorry, I'm learning so I don't know hot to DO it..could you to help me ? What is the next step to do?

Comment: Depends on how you installed your local copy... perlbrew or something else?

Comment: Maybe. I'm using a laboratory pc. How can I check it?

Comment: You have sudo access on a lab pc? Should probably talk to the sysadmins about installing it, anyways...

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much, anyway

Comment: Please provide the output of `head -n 1 ./RepeatMasker; type perl; type cpan; head -n 1 "$( which cpan )"; echo 'o conf' | cpan 2>&1 | perl -ne'print if /make|mbuild/'; perl -le'print "$_: $ENV{$_}" for sort grep /^PERL/, keys %ENV;'; perl -le'print for @INC'`

Comment: @ikegami : head: errore leggendo './RepeatMasker': È una directory
perl è /home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl
cpan è /home/fragua/anaconda/bin/cpan
#!/usr/bin/perl
Please make sure that the configuration variable
    make               [/usr/bin/make]
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/make]
    makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site]
   
.

Comment: mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       [--installdirs site]
/home/fragua/anaconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/home/fragua/anaconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2
/home/fragua/anaconda/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/home/fragua/anaconda/lib/5.26.2

Comment: hum, you changed directory! Please run `head -n 1 ~/RM/RepeatMasker/RepeatMasker`

Comment: 1) It looks like you have two builds of Perl installed: `/usr/bin/perl` and `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl`. The latter is first in your PATH. This is fine.

Comment: 2) `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/cpan` uses `/usr/bin/perl`, and therefore installs for  and therefore installs for `/usr/bin/perl`. That's not right. Could you edit `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/cpan` so the firs tline is `#!/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/cpan`. Then do `cpan Text::Soundex` (no `sudo`)

Comment: That should fix the issue if `RepeatMasker` uses `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl` (directly, or via `env`)

Comment: fragua@picci:~$ #!/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/cpan
fragua@picci:~$ cpan Text::SoundexLoading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Reading '/home/fragua/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 19 Apr 2019 22:17:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Text::Soundex'
Checksum for /home/fragua/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/Text-Soundex-3.05.tar.gz ok

Comment: ==> Couldn't mkdir '/home/fragua/.cpan/build/tmp-8585': Permission denied

==> Cannot continue: Please find the reason why I cannot make the <==
==> directory                                                     <==
==> /home/fragua/.cpan/build/tmp-8585                             <==
==> and fix the problem, then retry.                              <==

Comment: @ikegami this is the message that appears. Can I try with sudo?

Comment: You probably created directories inside of /home/fragua as root. Fix the owership and permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two builds of Perl installed:

- `/usr/bin/perl`
- `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl`.

`/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl` is first in your PATH. This means that programs with the following shebang (`#!`) line will use `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

`RepeatMasker` appears to be such a program.

All of this is fine.

**The Problem**

`/home/fragua/anaconda/bin` contains the scripts installed by `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl`. As part of the installation process of these scripts, the shebang line of these scripts should have been rewritten to specify `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl`.

However, the shebang line of `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/cpan` references `/usr/bin/perl`. This means that using `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/cpan` would install modules for `/usr/bin/perl`, not `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl`.

**The Workaround**

You could avoid relying on the shebang line and explicitly specify the correct `perl`.

```
/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl /home/fragua/anaconda/bin/cpan Text::Soundex
```

Or, given your `$PATH`,

```
perl /home/fragua/anaconda/bin/cpan Text::Soundex
```

**The Fix**

To fix this problem in an ongoing manner requires changing the shebang lines of the scripts to be what they should be. In every file in `/home/fragua/anaconda/bin` (and in particular for `cpan`), replace

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

with

```
#!/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl
```

You could do this use the following (which does a backup of the files it changes):

```
perl -0777ne'print "$ARGV\n" if m{^#!\s*/usr/bin/perl\b}' /home/fragua/anaconda/bin/* \
   | xargs perl -i~ -0777pe's{^#!\s*/usr/bin/perl\b}{#!/home/fragua/anaconda/bin/perl}'
```

Comment: Using `/usr/bin/env perl` is a best practice. It makes a script more portable, and allows you to better control your runtime without code changes.

It would be better to control this with either a direct path to the `perl` binary, or to bump the desired Perl path upward in the `$PATH` environment variable. Changing the shebang here doesn't seem like the best way to do this.

Comment: @manchicken, Your so-called best practice --it isn't-- fails on system with multiple Perls such as this one. You end up with scripts that are missing modules and scripts that use the wrong version of modules. [The script should already have the shebang line I mentioned.](https://pastebin.com/2y19BU04) This is something done automatically by ExtUtils::MakeMaker and Module::Build when it installs a script. (It's not specific to `cpan`, and it has nothing to do with `perlbrew`.) The script wasn't properly installed, and **the fix I proposed simply completes the standard installation process.**